# What statistical test to use for this experiment?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am doing an experiment to see if users are more likely to fall victim to a phishing attack if a mobile number is provided in the phishing email, rather than if it wasn't.

Participants are split into 2 groups. The control group will be sent a standard phishing email, while the experimental group will be sent the same email, but with a mobile number on it.

I am measuring the success rate of each group and want to determine if the experimental group is better than the other.

Is it as simple as just saying x>y so x is better? Or can I use a statistical test to help prove my hypothesis (that the experimental group is more likely to fall for the phishing attack).

I have tried researching online and have come across the t-test method, however this method assumes that the data is normally distributed, which I dont believe it will be, because the participants either fall for the attack or they dont.

Comment: It's a simple comparison of two proportions. In large samples you can use a normal approximation (and indeed a t-approximation works when the normal approximation works in spite of the 0-1 data), but a 2x2 chi-squared test of homogeneity of proportions is perhaps the most common choice. There are other options.  Many questions on site address this sort of problem

Comment: One of the many searches that returns relevant results: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=two+sample+proportions

Comment: See this example (found with a slightly different search): See here, for example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/508022/both-z-test-and-chi-squared-apply-in-testing-if-a-pill-makes-any-difference-in-a
$\,$ 
The z-test version is discussed in detail here: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat800/lesson/5/5.5